# Leaflet - do I need the rastercoords plugin for an non-geographical map with CRS.Simple and local tiles?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, tiles, gdal2tiles

I got a fictional map set up following this tutorial: https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

But when I try to switch the imageOverlay for map tiles (generated with [gdal2tiles-leaflet](https://hub.docker.com/r/niene/gdal2tiles-leaflet) via `docker run --rm -v pwd:/data niene/gdal2tiles-leaflet -l -p raster -z 0-5 -w none /data/<image> /data/<tilesdir>`), I only see grey emptiness. What do I need to change to make that work? Or should I better use the [rastercoords](https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords) plugin?

My code currently looks like this:

```
    var w = 4636;
    var h = 6000;

    //the stuff to be able to work with xy instead of latlon
    var yx = L.latLng;
    var xy = function(x, y) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
            return yx(x[1], x[0]);
        }
        return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
    };

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(w, h)];

    var background = L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'your Map',
        bounds: [[0, 0], [-6000, 4636]],    //the minus is apparently needed to avoid leaflet trying to fetch tiles like -3.png
        tileSize: 256,
        noWrap: true
    });

    var map = L.map('map', {
        layer: [background],
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -3
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds).setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: And how do you run `gdal2tiles`? Are you specifying a custom CRS to that?

Comment: honestly, I just ran it like this 'docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/data niene/gdal2tiles-leaflet -l -p raster -z 0-5 -w none /data/<image> /data/<tilesdir>'. I probably don't fully understand this yet, but the output are just some folders with png files. I thought the folder names define how they are supposed to be stitched together at certain some levels - were does the CRS come in play here? Shouldn't that be irrelevant for gdal2tiles and only  relevan to the map application?

Comment: `gdal2tiles` **does** reproject raster images depending on the values passed to its `-s`/`--srs` and `-p`/`--profile` options. That impacts the zoom levels of the created tiles (i.e. the extents of the tile pyramid) and so on. Do you have tiles for zoom levels 0, -3, 8...? How do the tile X/Y coordinates look like for a given zoom level? Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough on `gdal2tiles` profiles to know more with the information you provide.

Comment: Looks like I have to read deeper into the gdal2tiles doc. I thought the -p raster would be enough.

Comment: I found the answer over at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054833/how-to-use-leaflet-flyto-with-unproject-and-geojson-data-on-a-large-raster-i/44063119#44063119